# Symfony2 Travis CI Cannot open file "/home/travis/build/myname/myproject/app/bootstrap.php.cache"

Tags: symfony, travis-ci

I'm new to symfony2 and travis ci, so if this is a stupid question, I apologies in advance.

When I try to push a symfony2 project to travis I get the following failed message for my build: Cannot open file "/home/travis/build/myname/myproject/app/bootstrap.php.cache"

My .travis.yml file looks like this:

```
language: php

php:
    - 5.5
    - 5.6

before_script: phpenv config-add myconfig.ini
  - cp app/config/parameters.yml.dist app/config/parameters.yml
  - composer install

script:
  - phpunit -c app/

notifications:
  email:
    -  myemail@me.com
```

This error seems to get run after phpunit is called. So it seems like the build is okay, it's just that phpunit if failing on the above.

I tried adding chmod 777 app/bootstrap.php.cache just below my composer install instruction in .travis.yml, but that didn't seem to make any difference.

I guess it's a permissions issue, but not totally sure?

Thanks in advance.

Edit:

Actually, I'm not too sure if travis is creating the app/bootstrap.php.cache file. As I understand it, this should get done by the symfony bundle when composer install is run. But think this may be the root of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try

`1. sudo rm -rf app/cache/*
 2. sudo chmod -R 777 app/cache/
 3. sudo chmod -R 777 app/logs/
 4. app/console cache:clear 
 5. sudo chomd -R 777 app/cache/`

if it's doesn't help, tell me to know

Comment: Actually, I think as the error message suggests, phpunit can't find app/bootstrap.php.cache or there is some sort of permissions problem with this file. Don't think app/cache or app/logs have anything to do with this travis error. But thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

If your bootstrap.php.cache is missing, just run

```
php vendor/sensio/distribution-bundle/Resources/bin/build_bootstrap.php
```

Sometimes the problem is that the file is missing, and it's not a matter of permission.